# Polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

In SVD, 
$A=U\Sigma V^{T}=(UV^{T})(V \Sigma V^{T})=QS$

Here is an example.
$A= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
     1 & - 2\\
     3 & - 1
   \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
     0 & - 1\\
     1 & 0
   \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}
     3 & - 1\\
     - 1 & 2
   \end{array}\right) =QS$

I can't draw this answer.
Since $U$ contains columns which are eigenvectors of $AA^{T}$, and by calculation I get root value, so I think Q also has root value.
Can you help me to get that answer?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking? The polar decomposition example that you listed isn't right also.

Comment: That example is from the textbook. Is that wrong?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&10\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\ -1&2\end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\ 3&-1\end{pmatrix}$ in the first place, and $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&10\end{pmatrix}$ is not an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: OMG! That's my huge mistake! I corrected the number in the first matrix!